# Implement a trait for Iterator over values or ref

Tags: rust, iterator

I am trying to implement a trait that works for Iterator and Iterator<&u32> seamlessly, and while I did manage to find a solution I am not sure that is the best one, or even a good one. I have included my first two non working solutions for reference.

### Problem

Implement the following trait for iterators over u32

```rust
trait First {
    fn first(self) -> Option<u32>;
}
```

### Non working solutions

This first implementation :

```rust
impl<I> First for I
where I: Iterator<Item = u32> {
    fn first(mut self) -> Option<u32> {
        self.next()
    }
}
```

will work for `vec![1, 2, 3].into_iter().first()` (Iterator) but not for `vec![1, 2, 3].iter().first()` which will yield the following error:

```
error[E0599]: the method `first` exists for struct `Iter<'_, {integer}>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
```

using this second implementation:

```rust
impl<'a, I> First for I
where I: Iterator<Item = &'a u32> {
    fn first(mut self) -> Option<u32> {
        Some(*self.next()?)
    }
}
```

will fail this time on the `into_iter()` variant with the similar error:

```
error[E0599]: the method `first` exists for struct `IntoIter<{integer}>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
```

Note that in both cases the method is said to already exist, although the trait bounds are not satisfied. This means that it is note possible to use both definitions to have an overall working solution.

### Working solution

This works:

```rust
impl<T, I> First for I
where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
    T: Borrow<u32>,
{
    fn first(mut self) -> Option<u32> {
        Some(*self.next()?.borrow())
    }
}
```

while this works, I'm not sure how (what I understand of) the semantics of the `Borrow` trait would justify using it for that usage. Also I'm not sure how this is actually compiled in the end, but it seems a little pointless in the case of `into_iter()` to take a reference to and owned integer, only to deference and copy it.

Am I missing something to make this work, or is it a mistake to even try something like that (it's not much of an issue for Copy, but for Clone types, having a trait calling .clone() even when the type is already owned is a waste or resources)?
And is there any way to make the error message more explicit: to explicitly state that the iterator is expecting an owned value an not a reference, rather than the message about unsatisfied traits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementations are not actually conflicting, since no type can implement `Iterator` with both `Item = u32` and `Item = &u32`. The compiler is wrong here. This is [issue #20400](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20400).

Using `Borrow` is one option. If you can't use it, for example because you need different behaviors for different `Item` types, or because you want to support any reference level (`&&&&&u32`), you can use a workaround that is not convenient but works. The idea is to pass the responsibility of the impl to the associated type. The compiler cannot confirm that `impl Iterator<Item = u32>` and `impl Iterator<Item = &u32>` are distinct types, but it can confirm that `u32` and `&u32` are:

```rust
trait First {
    fn first(self) -> Option<u32>;
}

trait IteratorItem {
    fn first(iter: impl Iterator<Item = Self>) -> Option<u32>;
}

impl IteratorItem for u32 {
    fn first(mut iter: impl Iterator<Item = Self>) -> Option<u32> {
        iter.next()
    }
}

impl IteratorItem for &'_ u32 {
    fn first(mut iter: impl Iterator<Item = Self>) -> Option<u32> {
        iter.next().copied()
    }
}

impl<I> First for I
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: IteratorItem,
{
    fn first(self) -> Option<u32> {
        I::Item::first(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I do like that alternative version because of the explicit call to Copy when a reference is used. I can't use for an arbitrary ref depth though, it actually fails for &&u32. I think u32 and &u32 are going to cover most cases though, and although the error message isn't that helpful, it's actually pretty easy to fix the issue when using the trait by dereferencing the Iterator's Items

Answer (score 1):

The implementation constraining `T: Borrow<u32>` is probably what you want. This is one of the use cases that trait was designed for.

> Also I'm not sure how this is actually compiled in the end, but it seems a little pointless in the case of `into_iter()` to take a reference to and owned integer, only to deference and copy it.

This will be handled during monomorphization. When the compiler instantiates the version for `T=&u32` it will almost certainly inline the `borrow()` call and eliminate the indirection entirely.

Alternatively, maybe you don't actually need a `u32`, maybe you just need to be able to do something specific with the values. If you're doing addition, you could bound on `T: std::ops::Add<U>` for some `U`, for example. It's not clear if this would be a suitable solution since your question lacks the detail of your higher-level goal.